# React Native change drawerLabel dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and have an application where I need to be able to change the `drawerLabel` dynamically if the user changes privileges (moderator or not)

I set drawer label in the component

```
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Browse',
    drawerLabel: 'My Bookings',
    drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Image source={navIcon} style={[styles.icon, {tintColor}]} />,
    header: null,
  };
```

I was thinking I could change the label with setPrams, but the following does not seem to work:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.admin) {
      props.navigation.setParams({drawerLabel: 'Manage Bookings'});
    }
  }
```

How would I change `drawerLabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave this code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
   if (props.admin) {
     props.navigation.setParams({drawerLabel: 'Manage Bookings'});
   }
}
```

and try to change this:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  ...
  drawerLabel: 'My Bookings',
  ...
};
```

to this:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { params } = navigation.state; 
  return {
    ...
    drawerLabel:  params.drawerLabel || 'My Bookings',
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer kind stranger! It works, but only changes the name when the user loads the component (I shoulda seen that one coming). I think I may need to re-think how it gets its `drawerLabel` in the first place.

Comment: Took a step back and thought about it thoroughly for a second. I just ended up creating another drawer stack for admin. Super simple and works. 

Thanks for taking the time and effort to help! Have an updoot and check.